# Regex match element left before match

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I got a file with the following structure:

```
[section1]
item1 = text1
item2 = text2
item3 = text3

[section2]
item1 = text4
item2 = text5
item3 = text6

...
```

and i will find the section to a text. e.g. text is "text6" it should return "section2".

I tied:

```
content.scan(/(^\[.*?\]).*?#{text}/m)
```

but that is only returning the first section of the file :/
(i use ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/\[([^\[]*?)\][^\[]*?text6/m
```

This should work :)